# Adding Transient modifier to existing object

Tags: serialization, gson, transient

I have a Object Defined as

```
class MyObj {
        int a;
        String b;
        Date d;   //I will add the transient 
}
```

During serialization the object was without 'transient' and the serialized string contains the Date. Now I am adding the 'transient' modifier with the Date. Will it be able to deserialize?

I have tested with my machine and it is working but somehow I am not confident on this one. I am using Gson for serialize/deserialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.!

that is exactly the [definition of transient keyword in java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_(computer_programming))

## Quote

> transient is a Java keyword which marks a member variable not to be
> serialized when it is persisted to streams of bytes.transient is a
> Java keyword which marks a member variable not to be serialized when
> it is persisted to streams of bytes.